# Where I can specify the DTD mappings / URI patterns for DTD and xsd for websphere application?

Tags: java, xsd, websphere, weblogic, dtd

Getting error file not found for DTD in DOCTYPE. In weblogic we had weblogic.xml where we specified the uri patterns but there is no such thing in Websphere. the server looks file in 'C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AlertsProfile\bin\dtd\'. But the DTD is stored in /WEB-INF/ folder. Can you please help?